# Why is the jar file immediately terminated after being called using a Python script?

Tags: java, python

I'm currently programming a Python script that opens a file in an different directory that the user enters in an input box. Everything runs fine but the jar file I used for testing doesn't run or show up. I'm using the Shimeji-ee.jar in testing, and at one point its tray icon showed up but disappeared immediately.

I tried running it in command prompt(since calling the jar file using the script is similar to running a file in CMD) and discovered that it only runs as long as the CMD window is open. A few searches later, I've found a way to run files in CMD that keeps it running even after closing the CMD. I wrote it in my script, no errors, but the Shimeji nor its tray icon doesn't ever appear anymore.

I've added a line at the end of my script that is also told to be an efficient way of keeping the script running, but it doesn't work either(could be another mistake here):

```
while True:
    keyboard.wait('q')
    if keyboard.is_pressed:
        sys.exit()
```

Here's the line of code in my script that does the calling:

```
subprocess.run(['D:', 'cd', PurePath(fileDirectory), 'START', '""', fileToExecute], cwd=os.getcwd(), shell=True)
```

The code I learnt that makes a file run in the background(similar to adding & in a Linux terminal):

```
START "" program
```

I've had thoughts that the jar file I'm using could be the problem, but I haven't found any answers for hours. Is there anything wrong with the code or am I missing something?

**Update:
Code finally worked after the first answer but I received an error that seemed it read the file as a double forward slash like this:**

```
# The network path was not found //
```

or

```
# The system could not find the file //
```

**The solution I found was just removing the `'""'` part of the code, which makes the code look like this:**

```
subprocess.run(['START', fileToExecute], cwd=PurePath(fileDirectory), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code:

```
subprocess.run(['D:', 'cd', PurePath(fileDirectory), 'START', '""', fileToExecute], cwd=os.getcwd(), shell=True)
```

executes the command `D:` with the arguments `cd somedirectory START "" fileToExecute`, which changes the current drive of the shell to the `D` drive and then terminates.

You probably want to execute

```
subprocess.run(['START', '""', fileToExecute], cwd=PurePath(fileDirectory), shell=True)
```